# How to compare two different hashset objects with more than 100,000 records

Tags: java

I have two classes

```
class A{ 
  int id; 
  String name; 
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  { 
     if(o instanceof A) {   
           A a=(A)o;
           if(a.getId().equals(this.getId()))
              return true; 
       } 
    return false;
  } 
  public int hashCode() { return id;}  
  //setter& getter 
}

class B{ 
  int id; 
  String address; 
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof B)
    {
      B b=(B)o;
      if(b.getId().equals(this.getId()))
       return true;
    }
    return false;
 } 
 public int hashCode()
 { return id;} 
 //setter& getter
}
```

I have 100,000 A type objects and 100,000 B type objects.

So that, I have eliminated duplicates in both classes using HashSet.
Now i am comparing `HashSet<A>` and `HashSet<B>` with id field and place matched objects in another list with following code in main class..

```
HashSet<A> A_Set=new HashSet<>();
HashSet<B> B_Set=new HashSet<>();
    for (A c1 : A_Set) {
            for (B c2 : B_Set) {
                if (c1.getId().equals(c2.getIid())) {
                    matchedData.add(c1);                    
                }
            }
        }
```

the above code taking 15 minutes to compare 100,000 records...Is there any solution to increase performance of code.. (with in less time)

Comment: Suggestion: Use a `HashMap` instead of a `HashSet`. And don't post "Help me with this code" questions on Programmers.SE, either use CodeReview for working code, or StackOverflow for broken code (Not sure which category this is)

Comment: @JensG What about them? As far as I can see his `equals` is consistent with `hashCode`.

Comment: by comparing each value in set A with each value in set B you get 100.000 * 100.000 comparisons. Which is a lot. Advise to do a sort on both lists and only search forward.

Comment: I think this question fits perfectly here. It tries to know what's the best algorithm for his comparison. Pieter's comment could be turned into an answer with some more explanation around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two sets `as` and `bs`. You want to calculate the set `cs` such that it contains all the elements from set `A` which have an ID which is the same as that of any object in set `cs`. You are currently using this nested loop:

```
Set<A> as = ...;
Set<B> bs = ...;

Set<A> cs = new HashSet<>();

for (A a : as) {
    for (B b : bs) {
        if (a.getId() == b.getId())
            cs.add(a);
    }
}
```

This takes quite long because you loop through all elements of the set `bs`. It has algorithmic complexity `O(|as| · |bs|)`, where `|x|` is the size of set `x`.

We could apply one simple optimization: Once we've found a matching element in set `bs`, we add the current `a` to `cs` and continue with the next element from `as`. We do not search for further matches in `bs`, as adding a matching element again doesn't change the result set:

```
for (A a : as) {
    for (B b : bs) {
        if (a.getId() == b.getId()) {
            cs.add(a);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

While this should be quite a bit faster, this still has `O(|as| · |xs|)` complexity.

We can do better. For example, we could sort all elements by their ID (a one-time `O(n log n)` cost) in ascending order, and iterate over them using an `O(n)` algorithm that skips elements as long as they are larger than the current element from the other sequence. This is better, but still not optimal.

The optimal solution is to create a hash set of IDs of the `bs` set. This does not require sorting of both sets, and allows linear-time membership test. There is a one-time `O(n)` cost to assemble the set of IDs.

```
HashSet<Integer> bIds = new HashSet<>(bs.size());
for (B b : bs)
    bIDs.add(b.getId());

for (A a : as)
    if (bIds.contains(a.getId()))
        cs.add(a);
```

The total complexity of this solution is `O(|as| + |bs|)`. In other words, this should run roughly 100,000 times faster.

Comment: I would still opt for a `HashMap` of ID -> Object since the OP uses the sets to remove duplicates anyway, but it has the same idea. +1 for a good explanation.